# class not found after composer dump-autoload

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

I have a problem with compser autoload.
 If execute command "composer dump-autoload" then emerges error **Class not found** because *autoload_static.php* changed.

I have following structure of project:

**app** 
-- public 
------ *index.php* 
-- src 
------ *WordToImage.php* 
-- vendor 
------ composer 
------------ *(any composer files)* 
------------ *autoload_static.php* 
-- *composer.json*

*index.php*

```
 require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
 use wti\src\WordToImage;

 $loader = new WordToImage();
 $loader->saveImages();
```

*composer.json*

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "wti\\" : "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

*autoload_static.php*

```
<?php

// autoload_static.php @generated by Composer

namespace Composer\Autoload;

class ComposerStaticInit416f5acb57c46a86bf05d897e056b40d
{
    public static $prefixLengthsPsr4 = array (
        'w' => 
        array (
            'wti\\' => 4,
        ),
    );

    public static $prefixDirsPsr4 = array (
        'wti\\' => 
        array (
            0 => __DIR__ . '/../..' . '/src/WordToImage.php',
        ),
    );

    public static $classMap = array (
        'wti\\src\\WordToImage' => __DIR__ . '/../..' . '/src/WordToImage.php',
    );

    public static function getInitializer(ClassLoader $loader)
    {
        return \Closure::bind(function () use ($loader) {
            $loader->prefixLengthsPsr4 = ComposerStaticInit416f5acb57c46a86bf05d897e056b40d::$prefixLengthsPsr4;
            $loader->prefixDirsPsr4 = ComposerStaticInit416f5acb57c46a86bf05d897e056b40d::$prefixDirsPsr4;
            $loader->classMap = ComposerStaticInit416f5acb57c46a86bf05d897e056b40d::$classMap;

        }, null, ClassLoader::class);
    }
}
```

When I execute command "composer dump-autoload" then *autoload_static.php* is changed

```
<?php

// autoload_static.php @generated by Composer

namespace Composer\Autoload;

class ComposerStaticInit416f5acb57c46a86bf05d897e056b40d
{
    public static $prefixLengthsPsr4 = array (
        'w' => 
        array (
            'wti\\' => 4,
        ),
    );

    public static $prefixDirsPsr4 = array (
        'wti\\' => 
        array (
            0 => __DIR__ . '/../..' . '/src',
        ),
    );

    public static function getInitializer(ClassLoader $loader)
    {
        return \Closure::bind(function () use ($loader) {
            $loader->prefixLengthsPsr4 = ComposerStaticInit416f5acb57c46a86bf05d897e056b40d::$prefixLengthsPsr4;
            $loader->prefixDirsPsr4 = ComposerStaticInit416f5acb57c46a86bf05d897e056b40d::$prefixDirsPsr4;

        }, null, ClassLoader::class);
    }
}
```

And when I starting the project, an error emerges (Class not found). Please tell me why this strings:

```
0 => __DIR__ . '/../..' . '/src/WordToImage.php'
'wti\\src\\WordToImage' => __DIR__ . '/../..' . '/src/WordToImage.php',
```

are delete

Comment: try `use wti\WordToImage;` wti refer to the src folder, then if your is in src/WordToImage.php then the namespace is wti\WordToImage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:
1. The psr-4 autoloader definition takes an array of directories as the value for the namespace:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "wti\\": ["src/"]
        }
    }
}
```

2. As @ndufreche already mentioned: Try `use wti\WordToImage;`

Comment: Using a simple string is perfectly fine if you only have one directory for the namespace prefix. And this situation is actually preferable because other wise Composer would have to search for the correct directory if given more than one when loading a class.

Comment: You use `composer install -no --no-dev` to install the packages for production? This will generate an optimized autoloader, which uses a class map only. So you can always use arrays as described in the documentation.

Comment: That deployment optimization does not validate making wrong statements about the parameters for autoloading. Also note that creating a potentially huge classmap will take a huge amount of memory in the opcache and will also require more opcodes execution. At some point, this will take more time than simply searching for the files based on rules, so the general rule for optimization applies: If you want to optimize, first you have to be able measure it, and prove that it is better after the optimization.

Comment: A simple string will be converted into an array with exact 1 element. So the difference between `"wti\\": ["src/"]` and `"wti\\": "src/"` is, that PHP has to create a new array after deserialization, while in the first case it is already one. And I guess the optimized composer autoloader is the smallest performance problem in a large application.